# windows firewall and network location switch after establishing a vpn connection

Tags: windows-7, vpn, firewall, windows-firewall

I am looking for a reasonable solution for network location switching after VPN connection is established for Windows 7. The scenario is as follows:

- For location public (employee plugging in his laptop in hotel, public wi-fi,etc) all inbound connections are restricted, only outbound VPN + www is enabled.
- Employee then initiates a VPN connection, VPN pushes routes to 10.0.0.0/8 subnet

Now I would like to have lax security rules for traffic from/to 10.0.0.0/8 that comes through the VPN interface, while still protecting the laptop from traffic that comes via uplink interface as if it was private.

How to achieve this switching and duality? One option I see is switching to IPSec...

Answer (score 0):

Hey, if I am reading this correctly, you can easily set the advanced firewall in Windows 7 to accommodate; before a user implements the VPN connection.

Using the Advanced Settings console, you can configure the options for each of network type profiles